# How to install pyzipcode?

Tags: python, anaconda, sqlite

(1) I need to install pyzipcode. But whenever I execute command 
`conda install pyzipcode` it gives

> Syntax Error: Missing parenthesis in call to 'print'.

I am using Python3. I downloaded file from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyzipcod, but that didn't work either.

(2) I tried using pip command as well from https://anaconda.org/search?q=pyzipcode

Firstly it asked *is sphinx installed? If not try, `sudo easy_install sphinx`. Then it gave `Syntax error: Missing parenthesis in call to 'print'.` Whereas I have already installed sphinx.

(3)Then I tried to install with `conda install -c aaron2 pyzipcode=0.4`
Again failed and gave the error: `package missing in current win-64 channels: pyzipcode 0.4"`

Would somebody please help me out with pyzipcode installation?

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE!

Comment: Although Python comes up in DS, it is a more general tool, and this is more an installation question even than usage. Better for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Missing parenthesis in call to 'print'.` indicates you are using a python 2.x installation in python 3. Try uninstalling the current Sphinx and re-installing from 
http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/install.html

If using `pip`, use `pip3`, which is for python 3.x

Comment: I tried using pip3, again same error message: Missing parenthesis in call to 'print'. So should I uninstall python 2.7 ? Then would I be able to successfully install pyzipcode ?

Comment: Uninstall sphinx from python 2 and do some research to ensure sphinx actually works with python3. It looks like it doesn't so consider doing your project in python 2.x